# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" When calling FileUtils.readFileToString on xml files

Tags: java, xml, encoding, heap-memory, fileutils

My program iterates over a directory and uses the following function, from my Recoder class, to read a file using `FileUtils.readFileToString` on a encoding and overwrites it using `FileUtils.write` on another encoding.

However, when it tries to do this with an xml file, I get the exception at the title, otherwise, it works fine (i have tested on a dir with .java, .js, .css, .html, .jsp...).

```
public class Recoder {
    private static Charset fromCharset;
    private static Charset toCharset;

    public static void recodeToUTF(File f, boolean verbose){
        try{
            if(verbose){
                System.out.println("Convertendo "+f.getAbsolutePath()+" para UTF-8");
            }
            toCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(f);
            FileUtils.write(f,content, toCharset);
        }catch(Exception e){    
        }
    }

    public static void recodeFile(File f, String de, String para, boolean verbose){
        try{
            if(verbose){
                System.out.println("Convertendo "+f.getAbsolutePath()+" de "+ de + " para "+ para);
            }
//          CharsetDetector cd= new CharsetDetector();
//          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
//          cd.setText(fis);
//          fis.close();
//          CharsetMatch cm = cd.detect();

//          if(cm!=null){
//              fromCharset = Charset.forName(cm.getName());
//          }else{ fromCharset = Charset.forName(de);}
            fromCharset = Charset.forName(de);
            toCharset = Charset.forName(para);
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(f,fromCharset);
            FileUtils.write(f,content,toCharset);
            content=null;
        }catch(Exception e){    
        }
    }

    public static String removeAcentos(String str) {
        str = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        str = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
        return str;  
    }

}
```

The CharsetDetector stuff is from ICU4J, and for some reason it hangs when calling cd.detect() so, for now, I just left it in comments.

This is the main that calls it:

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
        DecoderArguments decArgs = new DecoderArguments();
        JCommander jc = new JCommander(decArgs, args);
        try {
            if(args.length>0){
                for(String s : decArgs.files){
                    File file;
                    if (decArgs.recursive){
                        System.out.println("Executando Recursivamente em: "+ s);
                        file = new File(s);
                        if(file.isDirectory()){
                            Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(file,FileFileFilter.FILE, DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
                            for (File f : files){
                                boolean exec=true;
                                for(String excl : decArgs.excludes){
                                    if (f.getAbsolutePath().contains(excl)) exec=false;
                                }
                                if (file.exists() && exec){
                                    if("".equals(decArgs.fromEncoding)){
                                        Recoder.recodeToUTF(f, decArgs.verbose);
                                    }else {
                                        Recoder.recodeFile(f, decArgs.fromEncoding, decArgs.toEncoding, decArgs.verbose);
                                    }
                                    System.gc();
                                }                           
                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Por favor, informe um diretorio para ler recursivamente.\n"
                                    + "Uso: java -jar decoder.jar <-r> Caminho|Arquivo");
                        }       
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Convertendo arquivo: "+ s);
                        file = new File(s);
                        boolean exec=true;
                        for(String excl : decArgs.excludes){
                            if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains(excl)) exec=false;
                        }
                        if (file.exists() && exec){
                            if("".equals(decArgs.fromEncoding)){
                                Recoder.recodeToUTF(file, decArgs.verbose);
                            }else {
                                Recoder.recodeFile(file, decArgs.fromEncoding, decArgs.toEncoding, decArgs.verbose);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else if (args.length==0){
                System.out.println("Sintaxe incorreta.\n");
                jc.usage();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Things to note:

- I'm using the following VM arguments on Eclipse -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
- JDK version 1.7.0_75
- I've experimented with some System.gc() but no avail
- It only happens when the main is running recursively(`decArgs.recursive=true`), the same file that throws the exception is recoded smoothly when
- Already checked the file encoding on bash and hardcoded it for a test, no luck there also.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Using `Recoder.recodeToUTF` method instead of `Recoder.recodeFile` causes no OutOfMemory to be thrown. Maybe trying to open with an wrong encoding causes the memory leak.

Analysing the .hprof generated, the (messed up) 300Mb xml file was using around 500Mb of the heap. However, the heap is set to an maximum size of 2Gb

Comment: How big are the files? Kilobytes? Megabytes? Gigabytes? Why do you need to read them fully, that seems very wasteful, can you try to process them as a stream (i.e. read a little, write a little, ...). And last but not least: if you simply "recode" an XML file without fixing the header, then it can easily end up malformed: if the header mentions a different encoding than what is actually used a confirming XML parser *must* report that as an error (if it can detect that).

Comment: the majority is in Kb, some in a few Mb, but for some reason, there was a pom.xml with 300Mb, very strange. I'm reading the whole file at once only for convenience, haven't found yet a File Stream where I could play with encodings, any suggestions? I'm currently replacing the encoding from XML files on eclipse, but I plan to put it in the code very soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your memory is being leaked so in order to check the problem you can 
configure your JVM with these parameters `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/dump`. When `OutOfMemoryError` get thrown a dump will be created in `/path/to/dump`. Then you can analyse it with [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://eclipse.org/mat/) and look for the objects that are leeaking your memory.
Nice tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html)